# How can I fetch certain type of data from Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know that there is a lot of code on this, but I can't find the solution for my problem.

I have a realtime database : [image]

I have to fetch "saluteBossMassima:"

The way I have declared and initialized my variables:

```
DatabaseReference databaseMonster;
String id;

databaseMonster=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("monster");
id = databaseMonster.push().getKey();
```

The code that I try:

```
databaseMonster.child(id).addValueEventListener(newValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String saluteMassimaBossDB = dataSnapshot.child("monster").child("saluteBossMassima").getValue().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the [minimal-but-complete/standalone code that any of use can run as is against your data structure to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the link please, as following the guidance in there makes it much more likely someone can help. For example: in the code you now have, we have no way of knowing how `databaseMonster` and `id` are initialized, and we don't know you you're processing the data that the listener returns.

Comment: Sorry my fault, you are absolutely right, now I have edited my question. I hope now it's better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work:

```
databaseMonster=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("monster");
id = databaseMonster.push().getKey();
```

When you call `push()` it generates a new unique key for writing to. There is zero chance that this is the same as the existing key in your screenshot.

---

If you already know the key of the node you want to read, you should pass that key to `child()`:

```
                   //   specify key here
databaseMonster.child("-MtcylP327pK9pUQB54").addValueEventListener(newValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String saluteMassimaBossDB = dataSnapshot.child("saluteBossMassima").getValue(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); //  never ignore errors
    }
});
```

---

If you know some value of the node(s) you want to read, but not the key, you can use a query to find the nodes:

```
//  Use a query to select the nodes with a specific value
Query query = databaseMonster.orderByChild("dannoAttaccoCaricato").equalTo(300);
query.addValueEventListener(newValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //  Loop over the results, since there may be multiple
        for (DataSnapshot monsterSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String id = monsterSnapshot.getKey();
            String saluteMassimaBossDB = monsterSnapshot.child("saluteBossMassima").getValue(String.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException();
    }
});
```

Now we need to loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`, since there may be multiple nodes with the value of `300` for `dannoAttaccoCaricato`.

---

If you know nothing about the node, the best you can do is read all of them and loop over the results:

```
//  Read all nodes under /monster
databaseMonster.addValueEventListener(newValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot monsterSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String id = monsterSnapshot.getKey();
            String saluteMassimaBossDB = monsterSnapshot.child("saluteBossMassima").getValue(String.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very useful. I've modified my code and now it works.